# Get MAC address of remote PC?

Tags: java, mac-address

I need to get the MAC address from a PC. The code I've written so far is here (this is only a small part of the code).

```
public byte[] getMac(L2PcInstance player)
{
    try
    {
        NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(player.getClient().getConnectionAddress());
        if (ni != null)
        {
            byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
            if (mac != null)
            {
                return mac;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        _log.log(Level.SEVERE, "No MAC address.", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This code finds the MAC of the PC I run it on, but I need to get the remote MAC.

Comment: :). i have edited my question. thnx

Comment: This can't be done remotely like @EJP said.  The client can discover this information and can send it over the socket (or via another means) to the server but there is no technical way to do this in Java remotely from the server.  Btw, this information is not even available to the kernel unless the remote computer is on the same physical local network I believe.

Comment: is any way how to identify a pc remotely ?

Comment: In terms of what?  All you have at a socket level is it's IP address.   You can maybe use the ident protocol but that's soooo 20th century.  Are you tried to identify a client for authentication or identification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that in Java, and if you do some research you will find that the MAC address isn't really much use to anything except the Ethernet layer and the NICs attached to it.

Comment: Hello, thnx for answer. i am already getting the mac of the pc where the server is hosted. so what i need now is to get the mac from a remote pc. that is connect with my server,

Comment: @JoinOG The MAC only really applies for the same logical segment -- if you connected to another machine through a router (P1<->ROUTER<->P2), for instance, only the MAC for the router would even make it to the local NIC... there are usually *many* different logical network segments (not all of which are even ethernet!) from one machine on the web to another :)

Comment: is any way how to identify a pc remotely ?