# Is it possible to get the visitor's mac address in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mac-address

Is there any function that gets the user's MAC address so I can record it as some authentication credential?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get MAC address of remote PC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046725/get-mac-address-of-remote-pc)

Comment: I honestly hope it isn't. (Oh wait, I'm always running a MAC faker? Nice...)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385/mac-addresses-in-javascript.  Typically an IP address is collected, but not much more than that is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Once you involve a layer 3 router, the original MAC address is no longer available / relevant.