# How to get unique ID of Android Tablet through ASP.net

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net

I have a website specially designed for Android tablets,I have 10 tablets it showing the website through Internet.This is for customer feedback in the airport ( using as small kiosks) Now i need to get unique ID of each tablets to store in my database How can i get the unique ID,I tried to get the MAC address but it is giving me routers MAC only

Any other solutions?please help me to solve this issue...

Binu

Comment: Ok if this is not possible suggest me a solution to identify the system again using Javascript/asp.net

Comment: See if this post offers a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046725/get-mac-address-of-remote-pc

Comment: Hi jfrankcarr This is in Java don't know Java and i am suing asp.net for my mobile website I need it in ASP.net or in Javascript Thanks for your response