# how to find client system mac address in web application

Tags: java, mac-address

I need to find client MAC address who is accessing my website. I have tried with java code.

```
try {

    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while(networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements())
    {
        NetworkInterface network = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
        System.out.println("network : " + network);
        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
        if(mac == null)
        {
            System.out.println("null mac");             
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("MAC address : ");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++)
            {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
            }
             val = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(sb.toString());  
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (SocketException e){

    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

But it display as **"network : name:eth0 (eth0)
MAC address : EC-A8-6B-77-A9-AD"** for all client system.

how can i do this?

Comment: You might have to access the driver stack to extract that information. Or try using api's of wireshark.

Comment: Is EC-A8-6B-77-A9-AD your computer's mac?

Comment: yes that is my server system mac address.

Comment: Might not be possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046725/get-mac-address-of-remote-pc

Comment: Pardon my french but why do you need client's MAC address?

Comment: @mostruash actually i need to give access permission for only 5 particular system out of 100 system.if other system try to access my application then should say message as restricted.

Comment: @manivasagam - It might not be possible as the mac address does not get out of the router the client is connected to. http://serverfault.com/questions/36002/getting-an-ips-mac-address-from-behind-a-router

Comment: @manivasagam Check http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/how-to-prevent-restrict-access-to-a-web-application-to-authorized-devices-only

Comment: You need to understand that MAC address isn't a reliable or even unique systems identifier. It can be changed by the user.

Comment: @Vinay mostruash Thanks for all reply.finally i have done this one using ajax.its working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Server side Java code will never return the client's MAC address.

For that you would need a code running at the client. For example in IE you could get that with Javascript+ActiveX. In other browsers (including IE) you could do that with a Java Applet, but security restraints might prevent the applet to access system information including the MAC address.

Comment: so i cant do in all browser using javascript or jquery?

Comment: ok fine.which one i can choose to detect instead of mac address in wep application?